Does this proof of $f(X)\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$ (for this specific $f$) imply there is an integer $k$ such that $f(k)\not\equiv0\pmod{n}$?
A generalization of the following statement is proven in "Primes is in P":
$(X+1)^n-X^n-1\equiv0\pmod{n}$ iff $n$ is prime.
Their proof of the only if part goes something like: if $q^k\Vert n$ ($q^k\mid n$ and $q^{k+1}\not\mid n$), then $n\choose q$ is not divisible by $q^k$ and hence, the coefficient of $X^q$ is non-zero, due to which the polynomial is non-zero.
However, it is not fully obvious that this identity holds true computationally - i.e. for each composite $n$ for some integer $\alpha$ that you plug in, $(\alpha+a)^n-{\alpha}^n-a$ is not divisible by $n$. And I ask this because another resource - Salil Vadhan's lecture notes on pseudorandomness asks as an exercise to use this identity to devise a randomized algorithm (in coRP) for primality testing.
Am I missing something obvious here?
Edit: I edited the title and question to something dissimilar to what it was initially. I had absolutely garbled up what I meant to communicate. My apologies to everyone that has already answered.
Primes is in P
Power of Randomization

The statement is only about polynomials, so bring it out the polynomials evaluated at on integer $\alpha$ is not relevant here. What exactly are you asking?

Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is the explanation of why you shouldn't.

$x^2-x\equiv 0\pmod 2$

$x^p-x\equiv0\pmod p$

Also, pick on, $x$ or $X.$ Mathematicians treat $x$ and $X$ as different.

Does $q^k| n$ mean that $q^k\mid n$ and $q^{k+1}\not\mid n?$

Use \pmod{n} to get the parentheses and spacing, not (\mod n).

Not even for $n= 2$: $f(x) = x^3 + x$ is even for any $x$.

So is $g(x)=x^2+x$
